# How to Make a Bag with Bag Container

Tags: c++

I have just been introduced to Bag container and need some help with it.
I was given some code which demonstrates how bag container is used. The problem is that the code I was give by my instructor contains some error which I am not able to figure out.
The error pops up when he tries to make a new bag.
Here are the header file and the actual cpp file

```
#include <iostream> // For cout and cin
#include <string> // For string objects
#include "BagInterface.h"// For ADT bag
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string clubs[] = { "Joker", "Ace", "Two", "Three",
"Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
"Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack",
"Queen", "King" };
// Create our bag to hold cards
Bag <string> grabBag;                  //<<<<<<<<<<<<error is on this line
// Place six cards in the bag
grabBag.add(clubs[1]);
grabBag.add(clubs[2]);
grabBag.add(clubs[4]);
grabBag.add(clubs[8]);
grabBag.add(clubs[10]);
grabBag.add(clubs[12]);
// Get friend's guess and check it
int guess = 0;
while (!grabBag.isEmpty())
{
cout << "What is your guess?"
<< "(1 for Ace to 13 for King):";
cin >> guess;
// Is card in the bag?
if (grabBag.contains(clubs[guess]))
{
// Good guess – remove card from the bag
cout << "You get the card!\n";
grabBag.remove(clubs[guess]);
}
else
{
cout << "Sorry, card was not in the bag.\n";
} // end if
} // end while
cout << "No more cards in the bag.\n";
return 0;
}; // end main
```

and the header file

```
/** @file BagInterface.h */
#ifndef _BAG_INTERFACE
#define _BAG_INTERFAE
#include <vector>
template<class ItemType>
class BagInterface
{
public:
/** Gets the current number of entries in this bad.
@return The integer number of entries currently in the bag */
virtual int getCurrentSize() const = 0;
/** Sees whether this is empty
@return True if the bag is empty, or false if not */ virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;
/** Adds a new entry to this bag
@post If successful, newEntry is stored in the bag and
the count of items in the bag has increased by 1
@param newEntry The object to be added as an new entry
@return True is addition was successful, or false if not */
virtual bool add(const ItemType& newEntry) = 0;
/** Removes one occurrence of a given entry from this bag,
if possible
@post If successful, anEntry has been removed from the bag
and the count of items in the bad has decreased by 1.
@param anEntry The entry to be removed
@return True if removal was successful, or false if not */
virtual bool remove(const ItemType& anEntry) = 0;
/** Removes all entries from this bag
@post Bag contains no items, and the count of items is 0 */
virtual void clear() = 0;
/** Counts the number of times a given entry appears in bag.
@param anEntry The entry to be counted
@return The numer of times anEntry appears in the bag */
virtual int getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const = 0;
/** Tests whether this bag contains an given entry
@param anEntry The entry to locate
@return True if bag contains anEntry, or false otherwise */
virtual bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const = 0;
/** Empties and then fills a given vector with all entries that
are in this bag
@return A vector containing all the entries in the bag */
virtual vector<ItemType> toVector() const = 0;
}; // end BagInterface
```

I'm stuck on this and don't know how to make it work.
Thanks

Comment: o god! what is this code???

Comment: Also, the header guards contain a typo and therefore won't work: _BAG_INTERFAE

Comment: `std::multiset` to the rescue?

Comment: I don't know what you mean @TemplateRex I'm brand new to this kind of stuff.

Comment: @JohnPeterson a `std::multiset` is the C++ Standard Library implementation of a Bag data structure.

Comment: @NoIdeaForName are you complaining about the fact that it contains comments? I've seen worse things

Comment: @sehe the comment are the only bright light in this code, do i really need to count all the bad things in this code?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName Of course you don't. It's still holy compared to most tutor-supplied code we witness here. I'm honestly wondering why you are raving about it

Comment: @sehe i'm afraid we'll have to agree to disagree... most of the code i see in SO i can make readable and understandable in max 5 minutes. not this one...

Comment: Have a look at my answer then. It's basically the same code minus the comments. Worked out of the box :]

Answer (score 2):

You were given an "interface" (`abstract class`).

(Or perhaps you have gotten a `Bag.hpp`/`Bag.cpp` as well, that you didn't show/forgot to include)

```
template<class ItemType>
class BagInterface
{
public:
    virtual int getCurrentSize() const = 0;
    virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;
    virtual bool add(const ItemType& newEntry) = 0;
    virtual bool remove(const ItemType& anEntry) = 0;
    virtual void clear() = 0;
    virtual int getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const = 0;
    virtual vector<ItemType> toVector() const = 0;
}; // end BagInterface
```

You will have to instantiate it and implement the methods according to the comments!

See a 'dummy' implementation linked in the comments: program prints

```
What is your guess?(1 for Ace to 13 for King): 1 
You get the card!
What is your guess?(1 for Ace to 13 for King): 2 
You get the card!
What is your guess?(1 for Ace to 13 for King): 4 
You get the card!
What is your guess?(1 for Ace to 13 for King): 8 
You get the card!
What is your guess?(1 for Ace to 13 for King): 10 
You get the card!
What is your guess?(1 for Ace to 13 for King): 12 
You get the card!
No more cards in the bag.
```

Comment: I would argue he has tried to instantiate it and failed. He needs to realise this abstract interface in a derived class, e.g. class Bag : public BagInterface { }

Comment: @achampion yeah, and the semantics of a "Bag" container are ... really messed up :)

Comment: @sehe There's no other Bagg.hpp or Bag.cpp file.
But how would instantiate and abstract class? I think it's not possible. Oh and the error is in the cpp line where it says Bag <string> grabBag;

Comment: @JohnPeterson That's the whole point. The "interface" was defined, ***you*** implement it. It's probably an exercise where you shouldn't use the standard library containers, because if you could, it would be extremely straightforward: http://ideone.com/aznLR0